# IPython: what's an easy way to export a cell with its output into a blog?

Tags: html, ipython

I am not interested in converting the whole notebook to HTML, just a particular cell. (I know, I can copy-paste the cell's contents into a new notebook, but I was wondering if there is an easier/more automatic way.)